# Crystal Select Case String required

Tags: crystal-reports

maybe I am being obtuse. My second select I am trying to get the first 6 letters of the field in order to cut out the text "Spouse First X"

```
select {vwAddressLinksTableView.DESCRIPTION}
case "Cellular":{vwEA7RecordsTableView.FIRSTNAME}&'-Cell '&{vwAddressLinksTableView.NUM} 
case left({vwAddressLinksTableView.DESCRIPTION},6)='Spouse': ''
default: {vwAddressLinksTableView.DESCRIPTION}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surround the

```
left({vwAddressLinksTableView.DESCRIPTION},6)='Spouse': ''
```

with cstr()